# New Security Group created while creating RDS cluster -- What is the IP address assigned?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, aws-security-group, cidr

A new security group can be created while creating a new RDS cluster (aurora engine, provisioned) via AWS console.

[image]

The created security group has inbound rule as follows:

```
IP version: IPv4
Type: PostgreSQL
Protocol: TCP
Port range: 5432
Source: 86.183.50.75/32
```

What is this CIDR value **86.183.50.75/32**? I have tried creating multiple clusters, associated with different VPC/subnets etc. The auto-generated security group always has this source.

Thanks!

Comment: Is it perhaps _your_ IP address? You can check at https://www.whatismyip.com/

Comment: You are quite right. That's exactly what it is!

Answer (score 1):

that ip address rage fall into public range category, i believe it may be your local machine ip address assign by your ISP provider(if so then it's not static also).

BTW, please don't expose your database as public, it's not a good architecture, from security standpoint it's not advisable to expose your database to outer world.

i would recommend to create a database in private subnet and restrict it's access from public subnet only, attach the SG only to allow ip address from your public subnet's CIRD range. finally create a bastion or jumpbox in public subnet to get access your database.